# Add a 0 in the next row of a column after the last data point

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-update

I have written a query which gives the output as shown below:

```
Date                           Amount
01-01-2020                          
01-02-2020                      10000
01-03-2020                      20000
01-04-2020                      30000
01-05-2020                      40000
01-06-2020                           
01-07-2020                           
01-08-2020
```

In the above table, we can see that the amount is null for 01-01-2020, 01-06-2020, 01-07-2020, 01-08-2020. Now, I want to add a 0 to the amount column for just 1 row i.e for the date- 01-06-2020 which is after the last data point - 40000. And I'm not sure how to do it. Is there any straight forward query to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that all populated values are contiguous? If not, does each group get dealt with separately or is it only, really, the very last value that triggers the zero?

Comment: The value 0 is not related to the numbers above in any way. I have to create a chart with the help of this output in another application and I have to have one 0 after the last data point. (in our case a 0 after 40000)

Comment: What if 01-07-2020 also had data?  What rows if any would you want changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and a  `case` expression:

```
select date,
    case when amount is null and lag(amount) over(order by date) is not null 
        then 0
        else amount
    end as amount
from mytable
```

If you wanted an `update` statement:

```
with cte as (
    select amount,
        case when amount is null and lag(amount) over(order by date) is not null 
            then 0
        end as new_amount
    from mytable
)
update cte set amount = new_amount where new_amount = 0
```

Comment: I'm getting 'Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses' when I use the above code in an update statement.

Comment: @BrawlX: I updated my answer with an `update` statement.

Comment: @BrawlX, please mark it as answer. so, it is helpful for others in future